# QuillJS keep HTML Font Format on paste

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm attempting to paste some stylized font into a quillJS editor and keep the formatting. However, the formatting is removed whenever I paste it.
I can create a clipboard matcher and have it set the font color manually, but I don't get to keep the original formatting. It's just replaced.

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/ashinyacorn/pen/wvvRoJp?editors=0011

And this is what I'm working with:

```
var Clipboard = Quill.import('modules/clipboard');
var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
var quill = new Quill('#editor');

quill.clipboard.addMatcher('B', function(node, delta) {
  console.log('How BOLD of you');
  return delta.compose(new Delta().retain(delta.length(), { bold: true }));
});

//Keep font formatting (size, color) ? 
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('FONT', function(node, delta) {
  console.log('HOW FONTY');
  return delta;
});
```

I would expect that if you were to paste in something that has a font styling, it would be kept. But it isn't, unless I override the delta and manually set the color myself. Is there anyway to tell the delta what the font color and style already is? Or a way to tell the clipboard to keep the styling?

Comment: Hi. Try to see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397115/why-does-quill-filter-its-content) can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled font size bug with a matcher also:

```
function preserveSizeFormat(node, delta) {
const match = node.className.match(/ql-size-(.*)/)
  const fontSize = node.style['font-size']
  // HACK: when className is not present, check style attribute
  const styleMatch = fontSize && fontSize !== '16px'
  if (match || styleMatch) {
    delta.map(function(op) {
      if (!op.attributes) op.attributes = {}
      // grab the size from `ql-size-{x}`
      if (match) {
        op.attributes.size = match[1]
      } else if (styleMatch) {
        const large = fontSize === '13px' || fontSize === '0.8125rem'
        op.attributes.size = large ? 'large' : 'huge'
      }
      return op
    })
  }
  return delta
}
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('span', preserveSizeFormat);
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('a', preserveSizeFormat);
```

I have found this solution [here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1083)